# Is my Tor bitcoind node seen by new normal nodes?

Tags: bitcoind, electrum, tor

I've finished the setup of a bitcoind node behind Tor like in method 1 of **[this guide](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Setting_up_a_Tor_hidden_service)**

I'd like to be as helpful as possible to the network and especially new nodes trying to sync.

Are new nodes able to see me right from the bat even if my 8333 port is only open using a .onion ip address?
Unfortunately I can't open port 8333 because I'm behind a firewall and my ISP charges for a public IP address.

If I want to set up an electrum server (electrumx) using .onion address will it be easy for normal electrum wallets to connect to my machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Are new nodes able to see me right from the bat even if my 8333 port is only open using a .onion ip address?
>   Unfortunately I can't open port 8333 because I'm behind a firewall and my ISP charges for a public IP address.

No... Onion sees onion, clearnet sees clearnet.  Your firewall is keeping you off of clearnet.

> If I want to set up an electrum server (electrumx) using .onion address will it be easy for normal electrum wallets to connect to my machine?

Yes, just tell your users to follow this:

- [Using Electrum Through Tor](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/tor.html)